# Excel 2010 to Sql Server 2008 Insert Statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I am going from Excel to Sql. I have the connection established. I can create a simple select statment and obtain values from a table in Sql into Excel. Now, I want to go the other way. I am trying to insert a value from excel into Sql. I keep getting a "Operation not allowed when object is closed" error # 3704. Below is my code.

```
Option Explicit
Private Conn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()




Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String

'This will create the string to connect.

sConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};Data Source=**;Initial Catalog = **;Trusted_Connection =yes;"



'Create Connection and the Recordset Objects.

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset



'Open the Connection in Order to Execute.

Conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = Conn.Execute("insert into TestTable(TestColumn) Values('50');")







'Check for the Data.

If Not rs.EOF Then

    Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs



'Close Connection

rs.Close

Else
    MsgBox "Error: No Records Returned.", vbCritical
End If



    'Clean
    If CBool(Conn.State And adStateOpen) Then Conn.Close
    Set Conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing


End Sub
```

How do I properly execute this statement? As I said earlier the select statment worked fine. all I did was

```
("Select * From KpiSetupOee;")
```

Any thoughts? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An INSERT statement doesn't return any records, so why are you trying to assign its results to a recordset?  Change this line:

```
Set rs = Conn.Execute("insert into TestTable(TestColumn) Values('50');")
```

to just execute:

```
Conn.Execute("insert into TestTable(TestColumn) Values('50');")
```

Then clean up your code to get rid of unneeded recordset references.

Comment: Thank you, I did as you said and it works perfectly.